# Ubuntu19.10のChromiumのログの場所がわからない

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, selenium, chromedriver, logging

Ubuntu19.10を使っているのですが、Chromiumのログの場所がわかりません。どこにあるのでしょうか?

seleniumからChromiumを操作していて、なにかしらのエラーが起こるのでその時のChromiumのログを見たいです。
どうも起動時のオプションに`--enable-logging`と `--log-level=0`を設定すると`~/.config/chromium`に
ログが保存されるようなのですが、見つかりません。

console.logの内容をログとして見たいのです。

[google chrome - How can I find my browser web log file? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1286937/how-can-i-find-my-browser-web-log-file)

[User Data Directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#Linux)

Ubuntu 19.10からChromiumがsnap packageとして提供されているので、そのあたりが関係しているのかと思っているのですが...

Ubuntu19.10のChromiumのログはどこにあるのでしょうか?

Comment: `--log-level=0` は冗長なログを抑制する設定のようなので、まずはこちらを付けずに `--enable-logging` のみで試してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 試してみたのですが見つかりませんでした。
https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

ここの`--enable-logging=stderr --v=1`だとstderrに出力することはでき、シェルからリダイレクトすればファイルにも書き出せますが、
Pythonのselenium bindingから使いたいので
リダイレクトを使わずにファイルを見たいのです。

Comment: リンク先には "If the environment variable CHROME_LOG_FILE is set, Chrome will write its debug log to its specified location. " と書かれていますが、こちらを試してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: できました!ありがとうございます!

Answer (score 1):

リンク先には以下のように書かれていますが、こちらを試してみてはどうでしょうか。

[How to enable logging - The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging)

> If the environment variable CHROME_LOG_FILE is set, Chrome will write its debug log to its specified location.

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/63677/ubuntu19-10%e3%81%aechromium%e3%81%ae%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%81%ae%e5%a0%b4%e6%89%80%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment69817_63677) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*